# What functions do I need to keep an eye on with 3rd party access to my server

Tags: php, security

I am normally responsible for all scripting on web-sites running on my server, but some of my clients have other people working on (parts...) of their sites.

When I give access, they can use php, so I regularly check if they seem to be knowing what they are doing, blocking people when they are:

- using mail() without proper input filtering (very common here in Peru...)
- trying to include stuff they really shouldn´t
- trying to use exec()

Are there any other functions that are potentially dangerous?

With dangerous I mean dangerous in all ways, from getting banned by search-engines and making spam-blacklists to compromising the security of the server.

Please note that I am not talking about people who want to do harm, but people who do not fully understand php.

By the way, I do not give them access to databases like mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the [System program execution](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php) PHP manual page, you'll see a bunch of functions worth disabling.

Note you can disable this from php.ini, using the disable_functions setting.

You also might to take a look at [PHP safe mode](http://ar.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php).

Comment: Thanks, I am going to take a look at those.